# SQL query not returning distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I have a game leaderboard comprised of 500 rows of data and I wrote a script to return that data and have no duplicate scores. However, I am getting duplicate scores returned to me. Here is my script.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    username, score, 
    FIND_IN_SET(score, (SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(score ORDER BY score DESC) 
                        FROM TPS_STATS)) AS rank
FROM 
    TPS_STATS 
ORDER BY
    rank ASC
LIMIT 100;
```

An example of the duplicate results I am seeing is posted as an image.

[image: duplicates]

Comment: There are no duplicates. Each row is different than the other. `DISTINCT username, score, ...` returns distinct rows of these columns and not distinct columns. Can you post what is your expected output?

Comment: I'm expecting it to not pick rows that have the same score because if it does as it has here then the rank will not be able to distinguish between two users with the same results

Comment: Then say for rank=1 which username would be selected? You do want usernames, don't you?

Comment: yeah I need username, score, and rank to be returned

Comment: Then this is the result you need. All users ranked by their score with ties.

Comment: I am not too adept with SQL and I'm not sure how to go about getting that. I thought the script I wrote was getting distinct rows but even distinct row wouldn't give me my desired result

Comment: Can you post this desired result?

Comment: The desired result is to not have rows with the same score. So in the picture, it should only have 1 user with score 670, 1 user with 665 and so on

Comment: I can see 3 users with `score = 659`. Which user should be in the results? One randomly chosen? And which rdbms are you using (sqlserver, mysql, oracle, ..)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189743/discussion-between-papab1ng0-and-forpas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of MySql is 8.0 then you can use row_number():

```
SELECT 
  username, 
  score, 
  row_number() OVER (ORDER BY score desc, username) rn 
FROM TPS_STATS 
ORDER BY score desc, username 
LIMIT 100
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vHFmFRqWu6uNr8hJdogbSm/0).
If it is lower:

```
select 
  username,
  score,
  (select count(*) from TPS_STATS where score > t.score) +
  (select count(*) from TPS_STATS where score = t.score and username < t.username) + 1
  rank
from TPS_STATS t
order by rank, username
limit 100
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i2zHyDJY8us8uahLqh539B/0)